# OpenGL 2d HUD over 3d won't render anything

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, 2d, sdl

I'm playing around a bit with OpenGL and SDL. At the moment, I'm trying to get a HUD to display over some 3d spinning cubes. However, when I added the code to draw a 2d quad after the 3d shapes, I got the black screen of death. Now nothing renders at all, including the previously working 3d shapes, so it doesn't seem to be a depth issue.

What I'm doing:

```
_SETUP_

Make a new SDL window.

Enable lighting and make a new light. 

Enable depth.

_GAMELOOP_

Switch the matrix to GL_PROJECTION and make a new perspective view.

Switch back to the GL_MODELVIEW matrix.

Draw some shapes.

Switch the matrix back to GL_PROJECTION and make a new ortho view.

Switch back to the GL_MODELVIEW matrix.

Draw a 2d shape.
```

The code (a bit messy, I apologize), draws a 10x10 wall of spinning cubes and has them change color:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
srand(12);

int x = 0, i, j, k;
Coordinate ang, pos;
Color color, colorMod;
SDL_Event event;
bool quit = false;

color.r = 0;
color.g = 0;
color.b = 0;

colorMod.r = .01;
colorMod.g = .05;
colorMod.b = .03;

pos.x = -5;
pos.y = -5;
pos.z = -40.0f;

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_OPENGL);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClearDepth(1.0f);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0); 

GLfloat lightpos[] = {10, 10, 10, 1};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos);

glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

while(quit == false)
{    
    //Draw some cubes
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(40.0, 800.0/600.0, 0.5, 20.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);   
    glLoadIdentity();                                    

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pos.x += 2;

        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            pos.y += 2;
            glPushMatrix();
            drawACube(ang, pos, color);
            glPopMatrix();
        }

        pos.y = -10;
    }

    pos.x = -10; 

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();  

    //Swap and FPS delay
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    SDL_Delay(10);

    //Makes the rotation happen   
    ang.x += .7;
    ang.y += .1;
    ang.z += .1;

    //Monitor for a quit event
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit = true;
        }
    }

    //Do the color stuff
    if(color.r > 1)
        colorMod.r = -.01;
    else if(color.r < 0)
        colorMod.r = .01;

    if(color.g > 1)
        colorMod.g = -.05;
    else if(color.g < 0)
        colorMod.g = .05;

    if(color.b > 1)
        colorMod.b = -.03;
    else if(color.b < 0)
        colorMod.b = .03;

    color.r += colorMod.r;
    color.g += colorMod.g;
    color.b += colorMod.b;
}

SDL_Quit();

return 0;
}

void drawACube(Coordinate ang, Coordinate pos, Color color)
{    
glTranslatef(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
glRotatef(ang.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(ang.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(ang.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 


glBegin(GL_QUADS);

//Top
glNormal3d(0, 1, 0);
glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);


//Bottom
glNormal3d(0, -1, 0);
glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

//Front
glNormal3d(0, 0, 1);
glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

//Back
glNormal3d(0, 0, -1);
glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

//Left side
glNormal3d(-1, 0, 0);
glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

//Right side   
glNormal3d(1, 0, 0);
glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

glEnd();
}
```

**EDIT:** I tried commenting out the 2d section, and got the same problem described above. Also changed code above to remove an erroneous clear of the color buffers (didn't fix the problem, but could be a problem later

**SOLUTION:** Had an incorrect gluPerspective line at top that messed everything after it up. Thanks for the quick responses, I apologize for the error

Comment: when drawing the 2d shape is it to always be facing the user? and is it to be a fixed size on-screen/fixed distance from the user, or variable?

Comment: Stays in the user's vision at a fixed size and position.

Comment: you may want to disable depth test before rendering the 2d hud, and then enable it afterwards again(wrap the quad render section in `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` and `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`, that's certainly what I have done in the past for huds, also, have you checked the draw order to make sure the last thing you draw is the hud?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|…)` in the midst of your rendering code, obliterating everything you've drawn before. For a HUD you probably just want to clear the depth buffer, but keep color.

On a side note, you should move the illumination setup right before drawing the cubes. You probably don't want that illumination for drawing the HUD, so you'll disable/change it before drawing the HUD.

Comment: No such luck, still rendering nothing.